# Postgres Bulk Update switches to sequential scan at unreasonably low threshold

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a large number of rows, around 260k. With data structured like this:

```
CELLS
id | values (float[])
-------------------
1  | [2.6, 2,7,...]
2  | [4.5, 1.3,...]
```

And I'm attempting to use a bulk update using the `FROM` syntax in postgres.

```
UPDATE cells
SET values[174]=update_values.val
 FROM (
        VALUES
        (1, 1.0), (2, 1.0), (3, 1.0)
) AS update_values (id, val)
WHERE cell.id = update_values.id
```

When I have 3 or less values in the update query, the query plan looks like this:

```
Update on cells  (cost=15499.17..11140840.53 rows=4692619 width=230)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=15499.17..11140840.53 rows=4692619 width=230)
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=96)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on cells  (cost=15499.17..3694060.92 rows=1564206 width=170)
              Recheck Cond: (id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cells_primary_idx  (cost=0.00..15108.12 rows=1564206 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (id = "*VALUES*".column1)
```

You can see that it uses an index scan on the cells table, and is very performant, takes well less than a second. 
As soon as I add a 4th element to the VALUES clause though, the query plan switches to a sequential scan and I can't get the query to finish.

```
Update on cells  (cost=0.10..11828380.08 rows=6256826 width=230)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.10..11828380.08 rows=6256826 width=230)
        Hash Cond: (cells.id = "*VALUES*".column1)
        ->  Seq Scan on cells  (cost=0.00..10577014.84 rows=312841284 width=170)
        ->  Hash  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=4 width=96)
              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=4 width=96)
```

The change from 3->4 updates is such a negligible percentage of the total number of rows, I can't figure out why the query planner is so far off on this.

The end goal is to break the update up it's current state (260k individual UPDATE statments) into reasonably sized batch-update queries, but the batch-update with the FROM syntax will not complete for anything over 3 rows.

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of the 174th array element to 1.0 for certain ids?

Comment: @AvinKavish the query needs to run for _all_ IDs actually, it updates one element of the array for every row in the table.

Comment: That would be best done with sequential access is it not? As for this particular issue, maybe the table is due for a vacuum analyse or even a re-index if that doesn't change the query plan. What is the total row count?

Comment: @AvinKavish Sorry, I should clarify that my goal was to break the query up from one gigantic set of 260k UPDATE statements concat-ed together into more reasonably sized chunks. I was hoping to get the values syntax performant for update of ~1000 rows at once. I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry, typed the wrong word. I updated my comment. POSTGRES version is 10.7

Comment: The planner clearly thinks that with 4 values, it is going to update 6256826 rows (which seems to be pretty much all of them). Are your statistics for that table up-to-date (e.g. does `vacuum analyze cells` fix this?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, doing a vacuum analyze corrected the query plan. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: If the data is coming from a source within the database you can use `update ..... select ... from ... order by .. limit y offset x` to control the batch size. Considering there are 260k updates to be made they surely must orginate from a table

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/routine-vacuuming.html